# Why is (type-of list) equal to CONS?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am playing around with Common Lisp and just realized that

```
(type-of (cons 1 2)) is CONS
```

and

```
(type-of (list 1 2)) is also CONS
```

However the two are clearly not the same because all "proper" lists, must be conses with second element being a list.

That said, when there are only two elements, the second element is 2, and first element is 1, neither is a list, but the construct is also still called a cons.

This gets even more confusing since

```
(print (list (cons 1 2)  3)) ; this is a ((1 . 2) 3), an improper list, but still cons
(print (cons 1 (list 2 3))) ; this is a (1 2 3), a proper list, but still cons

(cons 1 (cons 2 3)) ; is not a proper list, but is a (1 2 . 3), but still cons...
```

All are cons, but why isn't `(list 1 2)` a list? It can't be a cons because cons and list must be different types in order to be told apart in the algorithm for determining whether or not it is a proper list (and in turn, `(equal (list 1 2) (cons 1 2))` should be true; without this discrimination, there should be no difference between a cons and a list, there would just be a cons.

Can somebody please help me understand why it says that `(type-of (list 1 2))` is cons, even though it is clearly a list (otherwise it would be an improper list to my understanding).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Proper and improper lists are not defined at the type level. This would require recursive type definitions which is only possible to do with Lisp with a [`satisfies`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw70/CLHS/Body/t_satisf.htm) type, and in that case [`type-of`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_tp_of.htm) would still not return a type-specifier as complex:

> b. the type returned does not involve `and`, `eql`,
>   `member`, `not`, `or`, `satisfies` or `values`.

The [`list`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_list.htm) type could be defined as `(or cons null)`:

> The types `cons` and `null` form an exhaustive partition of the type `list`.

That means that `nil` is a list, and any `cons` cell is a list. See also the definition of [`listp`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_listp.htm).

In other words:

```
(typep '(a b c) 'cons)
=> T
```

But also:

```
(typep '(a b c) 'list)
=> T
```

And of course this is true for any supertype:

```
(typep '(a b c) 'sequence)
=> T

(typep '(a b c) 't)
=> T
```

The `type-of` function returns the most basic type, i.e. [`cons`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_cons.htm), which can be thought of as the type for which no other subtype satisfy `typep` (but read the [specification](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_tp_of.htm) which gives the actual definition).

#### Remarks

Just to clarify:

```
(cons 1 2)
```

... *is* a list, but it cannot be passed to functions that expect proper lists like `map`, etc. This is checked at runtime and generally, there is no confusion because the cases where one use improper lists are actually quite rare (when you treat `cons` cells as trees, for example). Likewise,  *circular lists* require special treatment.
In order to check if a list is proper or not, you only need to check whether the last `cons` has a `nil` or not as its `cdr`.

Also, I saw that you wrote:

```
((1 . 2) 3) ; [...] an improper list
```

What you have here is a proper-list of two elements where the first one is an improper list, a.k.a. a dotted-list.

Comment: This might take a while to digest O.o

Answer (score 3):

@coredump's answer is the correct one, but it's perhaps useful to see pragmatic reasons *why* it's correct.

Firstly, it's quite desirable that *typechecks are quick*.  So if I say `(typep x 'list)`, I'd like it not to have to go away for a long time to do the check.

Well, consider what a proper list checker has to look like.  Something like this, perhaps:

```
(defun proper-list-p (x)
  (typecase x
    (null t)
    (cons (proper-list-p (rest x)))
    (t nil)))
```

For any good CL compiler this is a loop (and it can obviously be rewritten as an explicit loop if you might need to deal with rudimentary compilers).  But it's a loop which is as long as the list you are checking, and this fails the 'typechecks should be quick' test.

In fact it fails a more serious test: *typechecks should terminate*.  Consider a call like `(proper-list-p #1=(1 . #1#))`.  Oops.  So we need something like this, perhaps:

```
(defun proper-list-p (x)
  (labels ((plp (thing seen)
             (typecase thing
               (null (values t nil))
               (cons
                (if (member thing seen)
                    (values nil t) ;or t t?
                  (plp (rest thing)
                       (cons thing seen))))
               (t (values nil nil)))))
    (plp x '())))
```

Well, this will terminate (and tell you whether the list is circular):

```
> (proper-list-p '#1=(1 . #1#))
nil
t
```

(This version considers circular lists not to be proper: I think the other decision is less useful but perhaps equally justified in some theoretical sense.)

But this is now *quadratic* in the length of the list.  This can be made better by using a hashtable in the obvious way, but then the implementation is ludicrously consy for small lists (hashtables are big).

Another reason is to consider the difference between *representational* type and *intentional* type: the representational type of something tells you how it is implemented, while the intentional type tells you what it logically is.  And it's easy to see that, in a lisp with mutable data structures, it is absurdly difficult for the representational type of a (non-null) list to be different than that of a cons.  Here's an example of why:

```
(defun make-list/last (length init)
  ;; return a list of length LENGTH, with each element being INIT,
  ;; and its last cons.
  (labels ((mlt (n list last)
             (cond ((zerop n)
                    (values list last))
                   ((null last)
                    (let ((c (cons init nil)))
                      (mlt (- n 1) c c)))
                   (t (mlt (- n 1) (cons init list) last)))))
    (mlt length '() '())))

(multiple-value-bind (list last) (make-list/last 10 3)
  (values
   (proper-list-p list)
   (progn
     (setf (cdr last) t)
     (proper-list-p list))
   (progn
     (setf (cdr (cdr list)) '(2 3))
     (proper-list-p list))))
```

So the result of the last form is `t nil t`: `list` is initially a proper list, then it isn't because I fiddled with its final cons, then it is again because I fiddled with some intermediate cons (and now, whatever I do to the cons bound to `last` will make no difference to that bound to `list`).

It would be insanely difficult to keep track, in terms of representational type, of whether something is a proper list or not, if you want to use anything that is remotely like linked lists.  And `type-of`, for instance, tells you the representational type of something, which can only be `cons` (or `null` for empty lists).